# Concatenate two fields into one field in graphql query

Tags: graphql

Let say I have the following schema

```
type Human {
  Title: String
  Name: String  
}
```

Now the query

```
{
  Human {
    Title
    Name
  }
}
```

Returns

```
{
  "data" {
    Title: "Mr.",
    Name: "Nielsen"
  }
}
```

How do I get combined/concatenated string "Mr. Nielsen" as a result?

Comment: Have you found a way to concatenate ?

Comment: Did you found any solution for your query pls

Answer (score 1):

You would add a new field to Human, something like `FullName: String` and the resolve on that field would be along the lines of:

`` (parent) => `${parent.Title} ${parent.Name}`; ``

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I need to do it without altering the type